# Android SQLite DB Upgrade - Code Structure (works in onUpgrade but not when called from there)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade, alter-table

I'm working on upgrading sqlite databases in android. I think I got the principles, but I can't understand the behavior of - in my understanding - similar code versions.

When I directly excecute the "Alter Table"-Command inside the overridden onUpgrade-procedure (Code 1 below), everything is fine. If I call a procedure using exactly the same (sql and java) code inside it (Code 2), the database is not affected. However, there is no error notice, and if I run the sql-code in a sqlite manager after pulling the DB-File using adb it works fine as well.

It would be nice if anyone could explain what is the problem with the "seperated version"?

Note: For creating the database, there is no problem in calling a routine from onCreate...

"Integrated" Version, Code 1, Working:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DBName = "DynamicValueTracker.db";
    private static final int DBVersion = 2;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName,  null, DBVersion);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int OldVersion, int NewVersion) {
        switch (NewVersion) {
            //(deleted further cases for posting question...)
            //This works
            case 2:
                String sqlcmd = "ALTER TABLE countries ADD COLUMN capital TEXT DEFAULT null;";
                db.execSQL(sqlcmd);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

"Seperated" Version, Code 2, Not Working:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DBName = "DynamicValueTracker.db";
    private static final int DBVersion = 2;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName,  null, DBVersion);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int OldVersion, int NewVersion) {
        switch (NewVersion) {
        //(deleted further cases for posting question...)
            case 2:
                DBUpgrade_V1_to_V2(db);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void DBUpgrade_V1_to_V2(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //This is excecuted without throwing errors but does not change the database table 
    String sqlcmd = "ALTER TABLE countries ADD COLUMN capital TEXT DEFAULT null;";
    db.execSQL(sqlcmd);
}
```

}

Comment: To confirm - You reverted your code to version 1, uninstalled the app, reinstalled, added the modified version 2 code and ran again?

Comment: Yes, I did that. I also reproduced the behaviour with different versions upgrading v1 to v2, v1 to v3, v2 to v3 and so on... (I only posted a shortended code version here)

Comment: And after deleting the database, always the correct version of onCreate is run from one different procedure for every version called from an overridden onCreate...

Comment: Ok just wanted to rule that out as onUpgrade would only get called at most once per database version (note you should also consider the possibility that you could go from version 1 to version 3 and you may still need to run some queries for the intermediary version 2). It's quite strange that your upgrade method is not being called if you're upgrading from v1 to v2.

Comment: I guess it's even stranger - it IS called, but has no effect! When the SQL-Command is executed directly in onUpgrade, it works, but not if I execute the same command from a method called from there...?

Comment: You're not starting a transaction somewhere and forgetting to call setTransactionSuccessful?

Comment: Hello - please excuse the late response - actually that might be a reason, from remembering I did not use setTransactionSuccessful so far during testing. I've meanwhile rewritten the code in a fresh class (whithout copying anything), and it works now. But I very much apreciate your help! Thank you!